# Compiling/Running Cocoa Project implementing NSSharingServicePicker in 10.7.x

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am learning about Objective-C/Cocoa and have downloaded the source code to [a popular TeX typesetter](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/texshop.html) and loaded up the project in XCode to play around with it. Compiling fails, and all of the error messages I have seen (so far) have to do with something called NSSharingServicePicker not being recognized. I gather (from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16955343/998619) and [this Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingServicePicker_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) that this is a class not available in 10.7.x. It therefore makes sense why the code won't compile on my Lion machine.

My question is, I guess, why I am able to run the downloaded package of TeXShop on 10.7 at all? (According to the website, this version is for OSX 10.7 and up.) I am interested in making a few minor changes to this project; am I not able to check my changes/compile unless I'm using a Mountain Lion machine? Is there some kind of update I can download for coding/compiling purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Xcode 4.6.*, you should be able to set your project to use the 10.8 SDK and get past the compile errors.  (That's the "Base SDK" build setting.)